# PHP 'get's' data without $_GET?

Tags: php, parsing, variables, post, get

I'm not sure if this is expected behavior. But if I host the following on my server

```
<?php
print $stackoverflow; 
?>
```

And I have another example.html which contains:

```
<form action="http://pinguincyb.org/roc/opdracht1/lawl.php" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="stackoverflow" value="example">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The page prints 'example', is this normal behavior? Shouldn't that data be unavailable until I would do something like

```
$stackoverflow = $_GET["stackoverflow"];
```

Comment: mehtod ?  just to be precise...

Comment: http://us.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Answer (score 6):

It's old deprecated feature PHP called [register globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals). Even removed.

YOU SHOULD AVOID IT.

Read manual about [Using Register Globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)

If you have it you must disable it. You can do it in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is old and deprecated. Avoid using it as it is unsecure

Comment: Yes, I actualy thought it would be a possible security issue, which is why i asked. Though I can't just turn it off, I'll bug my hoster about the config.

Comment: sectus and I aswered almost the same time

Answer (score 0):

On security.

As a matter of fact, for the well-written application it doesn't matter if this setting turned on or off.

A well-written application have to **define all it's variables** before use. If this rule followed, no `register_globals` will be able to do any harm.

If you have something like

```
$admin = FALSE;
if (check_admin()) {
    $admin = TRUE;
}
```

noone will be able to become admin with silly

```
/index.php?admin=1
```

even if register_globals is on.

Though one have to define ther variables anyway, just for the program's consistency.

That's the point.